# Different language resources

Tags: c#, wpf, resources

I need to create application with different language support. Language is setting up in login window (for example). I think I need to create a number of resx files and dynamically change em, depends on language I need.

Am I right? If so, how to make different resx files and change them in that way?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right. You will need separate resx files for each language. Once you change the language, translations from respective language file will be picked and used

Take a look at [this simple](http://www.wpftutorial.net/LocalizeMarkupExtension.html) tutorial. It uses the Markup Extensions for changing the language at runtime. It is a simple and elegant solution

Comment: Thats cool! Thank you! But I can't get it... How it works? :)